# Update blade view after Modal closed in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I would like to update my blade view after I closed my modal 
My Modal is like this :

```
                        <div class="text-right">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mb-4" data-dismiss="modal">
                                Set Selected Products
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <table class="table align-items-center table-flush">                      
                            <thead class="thead-light">
                                <tr>
                                    <th width="30">
                                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="isSelectAll">
                                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="isSelectAll"></label>
                                        </div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="col">Product Title</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Category</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Sub Category</th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach ($products as $item)
                                <?php
                                    $statusCategory = !empty($item->familyProductChild) && !empty($item->familyProductChild->category) ? $item->familyProductChild->category->is_active : null;
                                    $idCategory = !empty($item->familyProductChild) && !empty($item->familyProductChild->category) ? $item->familyProductChild->category->id : null;
                                    $category = !empty($item->familyProductChild) && !empty($item->familyProductChild->category) ? $item->familyProductChild->category->name : null;
                                    $subCategory = !empty($item->familyProductChild) && !empty($item->familyProductChild->category) ? $item->familyProductChild->name : null;
                                ?>
                                @if (!empty($item->familyProductChild))
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="article_related[]"
                                                    class="custom-control-input article-related" value="{{ $item->id }}"
                                                    id="article_related_{{ $item->id }}" {{ in_array($item->id, $articleRelated) ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                                                <label class="custom-control-label"
                                                    for="article_related_{{ $item->id }}"></label>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div style="white-space: normal; width: 125px;">
                                                {{ $item->title }}
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div style="white-space: normal; width: 125px;">
                                                <span class="{{ $statusCategory !== 1 ? 'text-muted' : '' }}">{{ $statusCategory === 1 ? $category : 'Not Set' }}</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div style="white-space: normal; width: 125px;">
                                                <span class="{{ $statusCategory !== 1 ? 'text-muted' : '' }}">{{ $statusCategory === 1 ? $subCategory : 'Not Set' }}</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

So after I selected the data in that modal, and I pressed the "Set Selected Products" button, I would like to show the data I selected in the blade view. 
My Blade view for that modal is like this :

```
                         <div class="col-md-8 form-group">
                            <label class="form-control-label">Related Products</label>
                            @if (count($products) > 0)
                                <p class="description">
                                    <a href="#"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#setRelatedProducts">Set related products here.</a>
                                </p>
                                @include('cms::article.modal-products')
                            @else
                                <p class="description">
                                    No Data Product
                                </p>
                            @endif
                        </div>
```

I would like the selected data to show up below that div. Do I need to add new jQuery for it to work? Also, I'm sorry in advance if this question has been asked before (I can't find it)